# Don't know where is the problem when I safely add the google MLKIT in the dependencies and ge this error

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, ocr, google-mlkit

When I add the google MLKIT in Flutter dependencies like this :

```yaml
dependencies:
  google_mlkit: ^2.0.7+8
```

I get this error in the terminal

> Because projectt depends on google_mlkit any which doesn't exist (could not find package google_mlkit at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.

[image: Error message: could not find package google_mlkit at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.]

I wanted to perform OCR on a Image

Comment: I couldn't find that package, check if is spelled correctly 'cause I found this
 https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit